# FTP Error 550 when trying to access a folder via symbolic link

Tags: linux, ftp, symbolic-link

I'm configuring svftp on a linux machine.

At the moment local users can login via ftp and they will see listened their home dir.
They have write acces to it.

No I want the users to write in de `/var/www/` dir. Therefore I created an new group `apache`.  Added users to the group and gave the group write access to `/var/www`. Via the terminal all users can write `.var/www/`. I created a link in the home directory to `/var/www` via

`ln -s /var/www/ /home/user/www`

`ls` gives:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 orangetux orangetux 4096 Jun 23 15:06 ftp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 orangetux orangetux 21 Jun 23 15:00 www -> /var/www/
```

But when I use FTP I see the link but I cannot follow it. Error 550 which means file not found or bad access.

How can I solve this, so that the users have access to `/var/www` via their home dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it [here](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/FAQ.txt)

> Q) Can I restrict users to their home directories? A) Yes. You are
>   probably after the setting: chroot_local_user=YES

But a more secure solution is written down below.

> Q) Why don't symlinks work with chroot_local_user=YES? A) This is a
>   consequence of how chroot() security works. As alternatives, look into
>   hard links, or if you have a modern Linux, see the powerful "mount
>   --bind".